# applications have a different theme when run as root in lightdm

Tags: xubuntu, themes, lightdm, display-manager

I changed lightdm's default theme and icon set to Flat-Remix-GTK-Dark and Flat-Remix-Green-Dark respectively.

which looks like this:
[image]

problem is when I run programs as root, which then they seem to use default theme:

[image]

I changed theme from this menu:

[image]

Comment: That kind of usual, I have the same on cinnamon and KDE. If you can perform the change without typing your password it means it is a user setting and thus it doesn't affect root (or any other user). You could change root setting by launching "Appearance" as root I guess. Also, you could look for the (user) set theme somewhere in `/usr/share/` (search for lightdm.conf) and a more global setting in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` (you'll notice you need sudo to edit this file)... I hope that helps.

Comment: I'd like to add that : there are very few occasion where you should run things as root, ugly graphics won't bother you long. Having a different appearance means you will never mistake root with non root. (I know it doesn't help sorry, I don't have the answer. Just though it would be worth mentioning)

Comment: You shouldn't be running GUI programs as root; you also didn't provide any release details.  When running as root any themes etc. set by any non-root users on the system won't of course apply, as those users are different, root's own setup themes/configs will be used.  This is a user issue (root is a different user to a normal user account.. and should be avoided! as it usually leads to problems in the future as file ownership can be easily taken away from the owner due to user error; performing a function as root when it should be done as user .. taking ownership away from owner..)